# Simultaneous connections on Apache

Tags: php, apache2

So, it seems that when a client makes more than 1 connection to the web server ( Windows + Apache 2.0.x + PHP 5.1.6 ) it dies.  e.g.

I put 1 phpthumb call - e.g.

```
<img src="/library/classes/3rdparty/phpthumb/phpThumb.php?src=/media/images/gallery/cart1.jpg&w=100&h=100" />
```

That works.  But if I put like 3 on the page, it just loads forever ( according to firebug ) .. and it never shows!

Comment: Did you check your apache2 settings in httpd.conf for maximum connections? What did your error_log tell you?

Comment: Apache error log shows no entries - error log level is on "info".

I'm not using any sessions, apart from it not working on the website, I made a blank file, with only 3 lines that I showed in my original post, and it does the same thing.  Using only 1 line, or viewing that phpThumb url in my browser shows the image though.  So it works doing only 1 request, but as soon as there's 2 or more it dies.

From httpd.conf :
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

<IfModule mpm_winnt.c>
ThreadsPerChild 250
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>

Comment: Can you check whether `session.auto_start` is on in php.ini? Was the blank file a PHP one?

Comment: session.auto_start was set to 0. I changed it to 1, but it didn't make a difference, still the same issue.  and additionally I got a notice about an existing session_start() that I have in a glboal include (config file)

Answer (score 1):

Browsers do limit the number of concurrent connections to a web server, simply queueing them up ready to be requested once a "slot" becomes free. The actual number of concurrent connections varies from browser to browser and even version to version, and can sometimes be changed by the browser's user.
Web servers may also limit the number of concurrent connections.

If each queued request takes a long time to run, then you could run into difficulties with this, making the whole thing seem very slow.

If you're using sessions in your PHP script, then it can be even slower, because only one instance of a script can acces sthe session file at a time... and if it doesn't release it's lock until it's finished running, then effectively your connection limit is being restricted to 1 at a time. One potential solution to this is not to use session_start() unless you need to; another is to release the session lock as soon as you've finished accessing the session file using session_write_close()

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but, there must be something I can do, server wise, to fix this?  Because it worked on our previous server, but that crashed completely in terms of hardware, hence the new one.  Possible security issues won't be a problem, because it's a local development server.  Any ideas?  ( in the case that I do need sessions and doing session_write_close() everywhere is out of my control )

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `session_destroy()` in your /library/classes/3rdparty/phpthumb/phpThumb.php

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP did you install, VC6 and thread-safe or not? I would look into that and switch to the correct one depending on how you use it (check http://windows.php.net/download/ - Which version do I choose?)...